# how to give opacity on area map

Tags: html, css, opacity

i am having a problem with html opacity ..

currently i have applied opacity using css but its not working 
my html and css code is below..

```
<area shape ="rect" class="transbox" coords ="0,0,30,22"
href ="test1.htm"  target ="_blank" opacity="0.5"    />

area{
 opacity: 0.6;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
filter: alpha(opacity=60);
-moz-opacity: 0.60;
-khtml-opacity: 0.6;
}
```

any one have idea about it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change opacity per `area` element.

However, you could still achieve an effect with [mapper.js](http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/).