# change opacity of image.map area

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a small image, with image map placement. Whenever area is clicked, I would need to change opacity of test2 area only, no matter if test1, test2 or test3 area is clicked. As I don't know jquery syntax very well, I would appreciate if you could tell me how to solve this. Thank you.

```
<img src="testing.png" usemap"testing-map" />

<map name="testing-map">

    <area shape="rect" coords="426,274,456,300"  alt="test1" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="456,274,618,300"  alt="test2" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="618,274,678,300"  alt="test3" />

</map>
```

Jquery:

```
$('area').on('click', function() {
 --- no idea --- .css('opacity', '0.1');
});
```

Comment: I think there's a Jquery Plug-in - https://github.com/jamietre/ImageMapster

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343531/is-it-possible-to-style-a-mouseover-on-an-image-map-using-css

Answer (score 0):

```
$('map area').on('click', function() {
   $('area[alt="test2"]').css('opacity', '0.1');
});
```

or

```
$('map area').on('click', function() {
   $('area[alt="test2"]').attr('css', 'opacity:0.1');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason it does nothing

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887953/how-to-give-opacity-on-area-map

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$('area[alt=test2]').css({'opacity':'0.1'});
```

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason it does nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this: 

    $('area').on('click', function() {
      $("area[alt=test2]").css('opacity', '0.1');
    });
```

This will change the opacity of all elements with  'alt' attribute text value equal to "test2".

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason it does nothing